# Mapkit rendererForOverlay bug

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

When using Mapkit's renderer for overlay, I'm experiencing an odd bug where the line pattern is not even on the map, some portions of the line are smaller than others (see attached image). I've also experienced another issue where the dots become enormous (not pictured).

This is the code for my line renderer:

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, rendererForOverlay overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
        let polylineRenderer = MKPolylineRenderer(overlay: overlay)
        polylineRenderer.strokeColor = mapView.tintColor
        polylineRenderer.lineWidth = 10
        polylineRenderer.lineDashPattern = [1, polylineRenderer.lineWidth * 2]
        polylineRenderer.lineCap = .Round;
        return polylineRenderer
    }
```

[image]

Comment: I found that removing the pitch from the maps camera fixes the issue in my case. Still not a great fix since I wanted it to be pitched.